# Split quantity of products in woocommerce onto seperate lines

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to put products as separate lines on the cart page and order process. So if a user selects 100 of the same product using the quantity field - it will split them into seperate lines, as appose to just showing quantity = 100.

I found this code online

```
/**
 * This hook runs at the end of the default add to cart processes, when you try to add an item to cart.
 * If trying to add more than item to the cart, separate them into individual cart items
 *
 * @author  Mike Hemberger <mike@bizbudding.com>
 *
 * @return  void
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items', 10, 6 );
function mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {

    // If product has more than 1 quantity
    if ( $quantity > 1 ) {

        // Keep the product but set its quantity to 1
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, 1 );

        // Run a loop 1 less than the total quantity
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity -1; $i++ ) {
            /**
             * Set a unique key.
             * This is what actually forces the product into its own cart line item
             */
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() . "Hi Mom!" );

            // Add the product as a new line item with the same variations that were passed
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
        }

    }

}
```

Which works as I need it to, however when adding products in high quantity for example - 50 at a time,

it lags and hangs for ages and when looking at the console log i get a 502 bad gateway error.

Does any one know any other way to achieve this without it being slow?

Comment: No there is no other… This is just for small quantities, so you should limit max quantity if you want to use that.

Comment: But why is it so slow? Surely there is a way to make it faster?

Comment: Take a better hosting maybe…

Comment: I'm with WPEngine. Expensive as well ?

Comment: For hosting with WooCommerce take a look to this article about [WooCommerce and share hosting](https://onlinemediamasters.com/speed-up-slow-woocommerce-store/#shared-hosting) and about [best WooCommerce hosting providers](https://onlinemediamasters.com/speed-up-slow-woocommerce-store/#fast-hosting). As you can see the hosting companies to avoid are SiteGround, Bluehost, HostGator, GoDaddy, Hostinger, **WP Engine**… and some more.